# Deselected item in ItemListener.itemStateChanged()

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

When I listens a combobox with ItemListener how can I know, what item was deselected when ItemEvent.DESELECTED is fired?

Comment: -1, people really need to stop being so lazy and take a look at the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html)

Comment: Pardon, some clarification... I need not the item itself - I need the index of deselected item! I'm not lazy and have read  a lot of forums and docs, but the only thing I've found is to use some custom class for every item having the toString() and some getIndex() method, or, iterate through the model and find the item's index. Both ways are bogus and unefficient

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ItemEvent.getItem()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getItem%28%29)

Comment: you should really point to the most recent [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getItem%28%29).

Comment: mre means http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getItem%28%29 , mre +1 x 2

Comment: Pardon, some clarification... I need not the item itself - I need the index of deselected item

Comment: @Andrii: why don't you save the index of last selected item and check against the current one(JComboBox.getSelectedIndex())?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly get the item index. The workaround is to get the deselected item from `ItemEvent.getItem()` and find the index by iterating over all items.